# Unity 2D - Change the sprite by script DOESN'T WORK

Tags: unity-game-engine, sprite

I have multiple images then push them into "Sprite[] sprites".
I create a gameobjectPrefab and add Rigidbody2d + Box Colider 2d + SpriteRenderer.
I want to Instantiate number of gameobjectPrefabs equal to the number of other sprites.
But it doesn't work, plz teach me the problem. The Sprites don't change:

```
public Sprite[] sprites;
public GameObject diamondPrefab;
void Start()
{
    CreateDiamondsListSprites();
}
void CreateDiamondsListSprites()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < sprites.Length; i++)
        {
            var go = diamondPrefab;
            go.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite = sprites[i];
            listAllDiamondsFromSpritesList.Add(go);
            // Here is sample : i add to list<gameOject> to use later
            Instantiate(listAllDiamondsFromSpritesList[index],listLocationPoint[index]);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Set the sprite on the instantiated gameObject, after instantiation

```
void CreateDiamondsListSprites()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < sprites.Length; i++)
    {
        var go = Instantiate(diamondPrefab,listLocationPoint[index]);
        go.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite = sprites[i];
        listAllDiamondsFromSpritesList.Add(go);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank @slky ! Now I understand the reason. I will find another way for my script

Comment: @PhanNhựtTrường If my answer solved this issue, please mark it as the answer =)